# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 72443 > 65536)

Tags: android, gson

im encountering this error in the build " Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 72443 > 65536) " I was trying to add IBM chatbot but i'm getting this error.

Im trying to include IBM chatbot to the app and I tried to implement gson but it isnt still working

**Gradle build: Module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'chat-message-view'

    publishedGroupId = 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview'
    libraryName = 'chat-message-view'
    artifact = 'chat-message-view'

    libraryDescription = 'Android library to create chat message view easily'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.7'

    developerId = 'himanshu-soni'
    developerName = 'Himanshu Soni'
    developerEmail = 'himanshusoni.me@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lrtapp.ardentmap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.cpiz:BubbleView:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    //implementation 'com.cpiz.bubbleview:bubbleview:{X.Y.Z}'
    //Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.9.0'
    implementation files('libs/Ab.jar')
    implementation 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.7.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Gradle: Project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven{
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting this error because you've reached (and went over) the limit of the android build architecture - a single DEX file can hold only around 64 thousand references.

To fix this issue you have two options:

- **Use multi-dex** - this means instead of having just one DEX file, you will have multiple dex files in your APK. You can follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) to set it in your build files. This might affect your min SDK version.
- **Use Proguard or R8** - among other features, these tools provide **code shrinking**. This means all of the code that is **not** used will be removed, and therefore the limit of 64k references should not be reached. You can follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) to set code shrinking up.

Comment: in your android\app\build.gradle add multiDexEnabled true to the defaultConfig. And add the following : dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
} Read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex